# Making xargs work in Cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, xargs

Linux/bash, taking the list of lines on input and using `xargs` to work on each line:

```
% ls -1 --color=never | xargs -I{} echo {}
a
b
c
```

Cygwin, take 1:

```
$ ls -1 --color=never | xargs -I{} echo {}
    xargs: invalid option -- I
    Usage: xargs [-0prtx] [-e[eof-str]] [-i[replace-str]] [-l[max-lines]]
           [-n max-args] [-s max-chars] [-P max-procs] [--null] [--eof[=eof-str]]
           [--replace[=replace-str]] [--max-lines[=max-lines]] [--interactive]
           [--max-chars=max-chars] [--verbose] [--exit] [--max-procs=max-procs]
           [--max-args=max-args] [--no-run-if-empty] [--version] [--help]
           [command [initial-arguments]]
```

Cygwin, take 2:

```
$ ls -1 --color=never | xargs echo
a b c
```

(yes, I know there's a universal method of `ls -1 --color=never | while read X; do echo ${X}; done`, I have tested that it works in Cygwin too, but I'm looking for a way to make `xargs` work correctly in Cygwin)

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you should update your xargs?

    xargs (GNU findutils) 4.5.12
    Packaged by Cygwin (4.5.12-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-n` argument of `xargs`, which is really the one you should be using, as `-I` is an option that serves to give the argument a 'name' so you can make them appear anywhere in the command line:

```
$ ls -1 --color=never | xargs echo
a b c
$ ls -1 --color=never | xargs  -n 1 echo
a
b
c
```

From the manpage:

```
   -n max-args
          Use at most max-args arguments per command line

   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.
```

Comment: There's no `-I` option in his version of ***Cygwin***. That's why he's getting that error. However, you're correct that he should be using `-n` to do what the OP wants. (Actually, he's better off with `find`, but that's another answer.

Answer (score 2):

[damienfrancois's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25568086/368630) answer is correct. You probably want to use `-n` to enforce `echo` to echo one file name at a time.

However, if you are really interested in taking each file and executing it one at a time, you may be better off using `find`:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 --exec echo {} \;
```

A few things:

- This will pick up file names that begin with a period (including '.')
- This will put a `./` in front of your file names.
- The `echo` being used is from `/bin/echo` and not the built in shell version of echo.

However, it doesn't depend upon the shell executing `ls *` and possibility causing issues (such as coloring file names, or printing out files in sub-directories (which your command will do).

The purpose of `xargs` was to minimize the execution of a particular command:

```
$ find . -type f | xargs foo
```

In this case, `xargs` will execute `foo` only a minimal number of times. `foo` will only execute when the command line buffer gets full, or there are no more file names. However, if you are forcing an execution after each name, you're probably better off using `find`. It's a lot more flexible and you're not depending upon shell behavior.

Comment: find cannot parallelize commands easily, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39377/parallelizing-upload/39383#39383 Still, those are valuable tips, thank you!

Comment: That should be `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec echo {} \;` with `-exec`.

Comment: @mgaert Thanks. Corrected the answer.